# Drop down issue when loading a partial - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on rails 3 and using ajax to load a form, there is a country drop down that has values thats not loading properly. Its loading html entities of the "<" and ">" sign like "<" & ">".

This is how i am rendering the partial that has the countries list

```
$j('#insert_to').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'verified_address', :locals => { :item => @item, :original_item => nil, :update_alert => false }).html_safe %>");
```

The output i am getting is

```
<span id=\"ship_to_country_container\">\n
<select id
=\"item_ship_to_country\" name=\"item[ship_to_country]\"><option value=\"\">-- Select --<\/option>\n
  &lt;option value=&quot;&quot; disabled=&quot;disabled&quot;&gt;-------------&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option
value=&quot;Afghanistan&quot;&gt;Afghanistan&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Aland Islands&quot
;&gt;Aland Islands&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Albania&quot;&gt;Albania&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt
;option value=&quot;Algeria&quot;&gt;Algeria&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;American Samoa&quot
;&gt;American Samoa&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Andorra&quot;&gt;Andorra&lt;/option&gt;\n
&lt;option value=&quot;Angola&quot;&gt;Angola&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Anguilla&quot;&gt
;Anguilla&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Antarctica&quot;&gt;Antarctica&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option
 value=&quot;Antigua And Barbuda&quot;&gt;Antigua And Barbuda&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot
;Argentina&quot;&gt;Argentina&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Armenia&quot;&gt;Armenia&lt;/option
&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Aruba&quot;&gt;Aruba&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Australia&quot
;&gt;Australia&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Austria&quot;&gt;Austria&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option
 value=&quot;Azerbaijan&quot;&gt;Azerbaijan&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Bahamas&quot;&gt;Bahamas
&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Bahrain&quot;&gt;Bahrain&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot
;Bangladesh&quot;&gt;Bangladesh&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Barbados&quot;&gt;Barbados&lt
;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Belarus&quot;&gt;Belarus&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot
;Belgium&quot;&gt;Belgium&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Belize&quot;&gt;Belize&lt;/option&gt
;\n&lt;option value=&quot;Benin&quot;&gt;Benin&lt;/option&gt;\n&lt;
```

html entities are getting rendered and not the actual tags

1st call: `$j.ajax({
            url: "/items/validate_address", 
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $j('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
            data: data_address,
            dataType: 'script'
      });`

this call the validate_address

```
    <div id="verified_address" style="display:none">
  <div id="verified_address_form" style="display:none;">
    <%= form_for(item, :remote => true) do |f| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'shipments/ship_to_address_form', :locals => {:f => f, :item => item}%>
      <input type="hidden" name="update_alert" id="update_alert" value="<%= update_alert %>" />
      <p><%= f.submit "Save", :style => 'width: 60px;' %> &nbsp; <%= link_to_function "Cancel", "$('verified_address_view','verified_address_form').invoke('toggle');$('order_address_id').style.position = '';$('order_address_id').style.zIndex = '';" %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div></div>
```

3rd Step: shipments/ship_to_address_form has the country dropdwon

```
  <tr>
<td><label for="item_ship_to_country">Country</label></td>
<td>
  <span id="ship_to_country_container">
    <%= f.country_select :ship_to_country, {},{:selected => item.ship_to_country, :include_blank => '-- Select --'} %>
  </span>
```

Comment: Hi, your verbal description of what the code is doing is not very clear. Can you provide an example of the html that is generated, and what you would expect instead?

Comment: Hi Taryn, i have edited my question, can you please help

Comment: remove `html_safe` from `render` call

Comment: Hello Amit, I tried doing that but getting same result

Comment: it might be getting confused as to which method is getting the args... try adding parentheses to be sure: `escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'verified_address', :locals => { :item => @item, :original_item => nil, :update_alert => false }))`

Comment: wait - show us the `verified_address` partial you have as well?

Comment: Hello taryn, i have added the code sequence that is getting called and the relevant code inside it.

Comment: `tr` and `td` doesn't have their respective closing tags in `shipments/ship_to_address_form`. You missed posting is here or is it missing on your code as well ?

Comment: No, the tags are proper just for the simplicity sake i copied relevant code. i might have missed copying the closing tags

Comment: If a place a norma select dropdown it works but with country select its not working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the issue was the country_select call, i installed the gem country_select and the issue was resolved. Thanks for all your suggestions and help.